# Write data back to Salesforce to envelope recipient (contact)

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have a question about writing data back to Salesforce from a DocuSign generated document.
The document is sent from an opportunity to Docusign, in the document I want to write back a custom field of the recipient (contact). The DocuSign document is generated for an opportunity object.

I have tried to get the recipient contact fields by

```
dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope__c > dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_Recipient__r > dsfs__DSER_ContactID__r > custom_field__c
```

and

```
dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_Recipient__c > dsfs__DSER_ContactID__r > custom_field__c
```

but neither of them works.

Is it possible in the DocuSign Console write the data back to the contact object (recipient)?

### Edit from Comment below:

I don´t get an error message I just see in the document that the fields are not related to Salesforce.

The Opportunity from which I generate the DocuSign Document has one or more related contacts but I want to write back the data to the Docusign recipient (contact) but I don´t know how I can get this data from the Docusign Console Tool.

First I have to select the object, I thought that I start with something like this:

```
dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_Recipient__c > dsfs__DSER_ContactID__r >
```

to get the contact from the related recipient but this doesn´t work.

I need to know if it is possible and how

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I'm not an expert in this topic, but it might help to get an answer if you include more context. For example, what do you mean by "neither of them works"? Do you get an error message, and if yes which one? Can you include some code snippet that might help spot the mistake? Good luck!

Comment: I don´t get an error message I just see in the document that the fields are not related to Salesforce.

The Opportunity from which I generate the DocuSign Document has one or more related contacts but I want to write back the data to the Docusign recipient (contact) but I don´t know how I can get this data from the Docusign Console Tool. First I have to select the object, I thought that I start with something like this:
dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_Recipient__c > dsfs__DSER_ContactID__r >

to get the contact from the related recipient but this doesn´t work.

I need to know if it is possible and how

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Please edit your question to include this information. As I said, I myself can't help you, this was just meant as a hint how to attract good answers.

Comment: @IngoSahm You are going to want to use a custom connect object. Here is documentation to further assist: https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/docusign-for-salesforce-connect.pdf